# Wrapping unmanaged C++ code with C++/CLI: pass resources

Tags: c#, c++, vector, resources

My question in about using a C++ unmanaged code in a C# project. I have very much (source) code C++ from my previous applications that work without UI. Now i want to give a UI to my code and i'm using C# for UI and C++ DLL as "calculation library". Now i'm using some wrapper classes for native C++ classes to create managed code in C++/CLI. The difficult I have is that my code use very much (static) data as input. This data are in particular tables and coordinates derived from my engineering works. I want this data to be inaccessible from external and also at time of native C++ applications I hate to use external .txt files to read data from. So I created in C++ code a resource manager class and i stock this data as strings and then i created some std::vector< > to stock my columns ecc and pass data to my objects. 
With the obsevations that I want all my "calculation classes" and "resource manager" to stay all, if possibile inside the C++ code for a question that I don't want to change my previous work, my questions/problems are:

1.) Exist a better way to embed this data and create this "Resouce Manager" inside code or my way is ok?, also in prevision that I have to use it in a C# application and I want it to maintain it inside the C++ code.

2.) If my method is correct, when I try to create managed code with C++/CLI it don't compile beacuse I used  std::vector< >. So I don't know what to do to compile this data in C++/CLI.

3.) Another problems i have is that some my classes often use std:vector< > so I don't know how to deal with it.

Thank you in advance.
Sorry my english. If are needed further explanation please ask.

**So thank you Walterfor your replay and so sorry for my long time answer. 
I made an example.**

This is my C++ header (vector.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

class Vector2CLI
{
public:
    Vector2CLI();
public:
    static const string m_stringVector2CLI;
    void SplitString(const string& resourcedata, vector<double>& vectorresult);
    vector<double> m_vectorVector2CLI;
};
```

This is my C++ source (vector.cpp)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>

#include "vector.h"


Vector2CLI::Vector2CLI()
{

    SplitString(m_stringVector2CLI, m_vectorVector2CLI);
    double ciao = 1;

}


void
Vector2CLI::SplitString(const string& resourcedata, vector<double>& vectorresult)
{
    istringstream iss(resourcedata);
    //vector<double> temp_vector;

    while (iss)
    {
        string item;
        iss >> item;
        vectorresult.push_back(atof(item.c_str()));
    }

}

const string
Vector2CLI::m_stringVector2CLI =
"0 "
"1 "
"2 "
"3 "
"4 "
"5 "
"6 "
"7 "
"8 "
"9";
```

Now i made a C++CLI code and in my header i have included the header of my C++ project:

```
#include "c:\users\...\vector.h"
#include "c:\users\...\vector.cpp"

using namespace System;

namespace VCcCLI_DLL {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

and it give me this errors:

```
- Error 1   error C2011: 'Vector2CLI' : 'class' type redefinition   c:\users\...\vector.h   7   1   VCc++CLI_DLL

- Error 2   error C2027: use of undefined type 'Vector2CLI' c:\users\...\vector.cpp 10  1   VCc++CLI_DLL

- Error 3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\...\vector.cpp 10  1   VCc++CLI_DLL
- Error 4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\...\vector.cpp 11  1   VCc++CLI_DLL

- Error 5   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\users\...\vector.cpp 11  1   VCc++CLI_DLL

- Error 6   error C2027: use of undefined type 'Vector2CLI' c:\users\...\vector.cpp 20  1   VCc++CLI_DLL

- Error 7   error C2027: use of undefined type 'Vector2CLI' c:\users\...\vector.cpp 35  1   VCc++CLI_DLL
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Doing it the way you described should be no problem. Another possible way would be to use string literals to embed your data in the C++ code.

```
static const char* data = "0,1;42,42;";
```

You can also store binary data this way.

```
static const unsigned char* binaryData = "\x01\x02\x03\x04";
```

If your data is very big you could also compress it before converting it to a string literal and then uncompress it in memory once you need it.

As we are talking about Windows you could of course als embed your data in the Resources as well.

2.) In my company we use C++/CLI to create bridges both from C# -> C++ and C++ > C#. We also use std::vector in some cases and don't have any problems with it. Could you provide an example of code that does not compile?